# Is it possible to add custom text in tinymce toolbar?

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce

I want to add an custom text to timymce's toolbar.

Example picture:

[image: example]

Is this possible and how can I achieve this?

Comment: You can add a button. Is that ok ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want to create a custom button etc. You could do this with css. For example:

```
.mce-container-body::after {
    content: 'Custom Text Here';
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    right: 8px;
    top: 5px;
    color: red;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```